# How to replace NOT IN with NOT EXISTS SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, not-exists

How can I replace NOT IN with NOT EXISTS without a subquery like in this case

```
DECLARE 
@var1 VARCHAR(50),
@var2 VARCHAR(50)

SELECT * 
FROM tab1 AS t1
INNER JOIN tab2 AS t2
ON t1.col = t2.col

WHERE t1.col2 LIKE 'text%'
AND t2.col2 NOT IN (@var1, @var2 )
```

Comment: Why do you need an `NOT EXISTS` rather than `NOT IN`?

Comment: `NOT IN` is the right choice here. `(NOT) EXISTS` is better used with subqueries, not a list of values.

Comment: Because I'm trying to optimize a query that is running very slow @HoneyBadger

Comment: I want it to perform a seek instead of a scan @Larnu

Comment: An `EXISTS` isn't going to change that, @mzansiedition . Indexing in going to help that.

Comment: Have you checked the explain plan?

Comment: Smells like parameter sniffing.